# Unity: make joystick fill whole screen?

Tags: c#, user-interface, unity-game-engine, joystick

Ok, so I have a standard joystick downloaded from Unity asset store, script here (isn't that long):

```
// Implement IPointerDownHandler, IPointerUpHandler, IDragHandler to subscribe to pointer events
public class Joystick : MonoBehaviour, IPointerDownHandler, IPointerUpHandler, IDragHandler {
    public delegate void JoystickAction(Vector2 joystickAxes);
    public static event JoystickAction JoystickMoved;

    public Vector2 joystickAxes;

    public bool usingJoystick;
    private Image bgImg;
    private Image stickImg;
    private RectTransform bgTransform;
    private RectTransform stickTransform;

    // The first tap is treated similar to any following detection of a drag
    public virtual void OnPointerDown(PointerEventData ped) {
        usingJoystick = true;
        OnDrag (ped);
    }

    public virtual void OnPointerUp(PointerEventData ped) {
        usingJoystick = false;
        joystickAxes = stickImg.GetComponent<RectTransform> ().anchoredPosition = Vector2.zero;
        //joystickAxes = new Vector2(Screen.height / 2, Screen.width/2);

        if (JoystickMoved != null) JoystickMoved (Vector2.zero);
    }

    public virtual void OnDrag(PointerEventData ped) {
        Vector2 rectPos;

        if (RectTransformUtility.ScreenPointToLocalPointInRectangle(
                bgImg.rectTransform,
                ped.position,
                ped.enterEventCamera,
                out rectPos)) { // Check if the pointer is positioned on the joystick
            // Clamp the position to be inside the image bounds, prevents dragging beyond the image to get higher values.
            Vector2 clampedPos = GetClampedPosition (rectPos); 

            // Normalize the joystick axes to be between -1 and 1.
            joystickAxes = new Vector2 (
                clampedPos.x / (bgTransform.rect.width / 2f),
                clampedPos.y / (bgTransform.rect.height / 2f));

            // Set the position of the inner joystick.
            if (joystickAxes.magnitude > 1f) { // Normalizing the clampedPos constrains the joystick positions to a circle
                stickImg.GetComponent<RectTransform> ().anchoredPosition = clampedPos.normalized * stickTransform.rect.width;
            } else {
                stickImg.GetComponent<RectTransform> ().anchoredPosition = clampedPos;
            }
        }
    }

    private Vector2 GetClampedPosition(Vector2 pos) {
        Vector2 bgMin = bgTransform.rect.min;
        Vector2 bgMax = bgTransform.rect.max;

        return new Vector2 (
            Mathf.Clamp (pos.x, bgMin.x, bgMax.x),
            Mathf.Clamp (pos.y, bgMin.y, bgMax.y));
    }

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        joystickAxes = new Vector2 ();

        bgImg = GetComponent<Image> ();
        stickImg = transform.GetChild (0).GetComponent<Image> ();

        bgTransform = gameObject.GetComponent<RectTransform> ();
        stickTransform = transform.GetChild (0).GetComponent<RectTransform> ();
    }

    void Update() {
        if (usingJoystick && JoystickMoved != null) {
            JoystickMoved (joystickAxes);
        }
    }
}
```

This relies on an image object on a canvas and another image for the knob. as pictured:

[image]

This all works well, however I want the joystick to BE the screen, meaning the outside bounds for the knob aren't the background image but the screen bounds itself.

Ive tried scaling the background image to the screen using rh canvas, etc but this makes the inputAxes values way off. How can I do this?

I want to keep this script, just tweak it so the background "image"/bounds are the screen, whatever size that is.

Comment: the script itself constrains the inner joystick movement to a circle. without changing the script, I doubt u can have its movement constrained to a rectangle (i.e the shape of the screen)

Comment: Ok - then how can I change it to be a rectangle? Ill change the script